# Could not open Monodevelop after installation.

Tags: unity-game-engine, installation, monodevelop

I receive the following errors in the log file, when trying to open MonoDevelop-Unity-4.0 in windows 8.

```
FATAL ERROR [2015-10-19 16:59:49Z]: MonoDevelop-Unity failed to start. Some of the assemblies required to run MonoDevelop-Unity (for example gtk-sharp)may not be properly installed in the GAC.

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Net.ServicePointManager' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Net.ComNetOS' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize()
at System.Net.Logging.InitializeLogging()
at System.Net.Logging.get_On()
at System.Net.ComNetOS..cctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.ServicePointManager.get_PersistentConnectionLimit()
at System.Net.ServicePointManager..cctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.ServicePointManager.get_ServerCertificateValidationCallback()
at MonoDevelop.Core.Runtime.Initialize(Boolean updateAddinRegistry) in c:\buildslave\monodevelop\build\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Core\MonoDevelop.Core\Runtime.cs:line 70
at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run(MonoDevelopOptions options) in c:\buildslave\monodevelop\build\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide\IdeStartup.cs:line 142
at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main(String[] args) in c:\buildslave\monodevelop\build\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide\IdeStartup.cs:line 542
```

I guess the error is related to the Microsoft.Net framework version. But I don't know to fix this issue. Please help.!!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the reason behind this, but every 10 to 15 builds I run will break my MonoDevelop IDE. I keep the gtk-sharp installer on my desktop for quick repairs.

**Repair Process:**

- Go to Monodevelop Site (http://www.monodevelop.com/download/)
- Click the link -> GTK# for .NET: Download from mono-project.com
- After downloading file, run it
- Select repair
- Get back to work

My dev box is a windows 10 and for the last few months this occurs way to frequently for me to believe that I am breaking the IDE.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and I solved it by downloading [Gtk# for .Net from here](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-win).

After that, I started it and chose the option to remove Gtk# from the PC.
Then I run it again and installed it normally.
After that, *monoDevelop* started normally again.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first test would just be to run the program as an admin, which in this case probably wouldn't fix it, but it doesn't hurt to try. If that doesn't work, then according to the crash log, it can't load because it can't locate the 'system.configuration' file. Which in that case your going to want to download the MonoDevelop installer separately and install with that so it can properly install its dependencies, which it for some reason happened to miss the first time.

Your going to want to go here to get the installer: http://www.monodevelop.com/

Although, if the error *is* with the .Net Framework, then just go here to download it/update it: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851

Comment: I get this error when I tried to install .Net Framework.               . --Microsoft .NET Framework 4 is already a part of this operating system.  You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4 redistributable. 
Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4 has already been installed on this computer. I installed the monodevelop seperately with gtk from the site( http://www.monodevelop.com/), but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

> MonoDevelop-Unity failed to start. Some of the assemblies required to
>   run MonoDevelop-Unity (for example gtk-sharp) may not be properly
>   installed in the GAC.

Do you have GTK# installed?

[GTK# for .NET Installer for running Gtk#-based applications on Microsoft .NET](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-win)

Comment: Yes I have installed it.